# What does the to_i argument base actually do?

Tags: ruby

What is the base argument on the `to_i` String#method actually do?

**Some examples:**

- `"2".to_i(2) == 0`
- `"2".to_i(36) == 2`
- `"2".to_i(4) == 2`
- `"ff".to_i(36) == 555`
- `"ff".to_i(16) == 255`

*On Binary:*

- `"1000".to_i(2) == 8`
- `"1000".to_i(16) == 4096`

*The docs say:*

> to_i(base=10) → integer
>
> Returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as an
>   integer base base (between 2 and 36). Extraneous characters past the
>   end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at
>   the start of str, 0 is returned. This method never raises an exception
>   when base is valid.

However, I am still unclear by this explanation, can someone please explain. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-to_i

Comment: @CBroe I read the docs. I'm still unclear. See edit. Please advise is you can. Thanks.

Comment: `[8] pry(main)> 123345.to_s(36)
=> "2n69"
[9] pry(main)> "2n69".to_i(36)
=> 123345` this is converting to and from base 36 for example

Comment: @feed_me_code: What part is unclear to you?

Comment: and you should not be able to pass a `Range` as a parameter to `to_i`, it accepts only integers

Comment: @Blender what exactly is this concept of base? I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @feed_me_code: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix

Comment: @bjhaid I wasn't passing a range, see the edit. I was just saying that any number in the range of 3..36 will return 2 when `"2".to_i`

Comment: @CBroe no I haven't. Is that what Blender is referring to about Radix?

Comment: If you don't understand the concept of a base in general, you won't understand the argument. Basically (bad pun), a base is how a number is written. So, in decimal, we have ten digits: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. A number that is one of the digits will just be that. To represent numbers bigger than that, we add columns. So 19 is a 1 I. The tens column (one 10) plus a 9 in the ones column (a 9). So in binary, a one in the ones column means + 1*1. A 1 in the twos column means + 1*2, and so on.

Comment: The base of a number is how many digits there are in that number system. In decimal we have ten digits. The first column is always the base^0 column (1). The next is the base^1 column, the next base^2 column, and so on. So in decimal we have the ones column, tens, hundreds, thousands. In binary we have the ones, twos, fours, eights, and so on. The value of the number is the sum of the digit in each column times the name of that column. That's why 19 in decimal is 19 (1 * 10 + 9*1), but if you interpret it as hexidecimal, you get 25 (1 * 16 + 9 * 1).

Comment: @feed_me_code: base 10 is what we he'd everyday, also known as decimal. 19 is 19 in decimal. And I assume you meant `"23".to_i(8)`.

Comment: @Linuxios I think I understand now. Not knowing: `Hexadecimal (base 16), Decimal (base 10), Octal (base 8), Binary (base 2)` was the most confusing part. What do the other bases represent? Seeing that Ruby allows up to base 36. What is 17 or 23 or 36 for example? What would you use 36 for? Do these bases have a specific purpose?

Comment: Nothing in particular. They are just systems.

Comment: @feed_me_code: Numbers are numbers, regardless of the number system you use. `1000` in base 2 and `8` in base 10 represent exactly the same number, regardless of how they're written. Since we only have 10 digits and 26 ASCII letters, you can only represent numbers in bases up to 36 using those characters. Counting in base-36 is like `0`, `1`, ..., `9`, `A`, `B`, ..., `Z`. You can go as far as you'd like if you keep adding new "digits".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This argument specifies the number system the the receiver represents. In computer fields you encounter three common number systems. They are:

- Hexadecimal (base 16)
- Octal (base 8)
- Binary (base 2)

You can think of these as being the number of "characters" you cycle through before starting a new "place". For example once you go from 0 to 9 you start over at 0.

When you ask the object to convert itself to a number, it has to know what it currently represents. Once it knows this, by you specifying, it can do the math to convert the number. An example of why this is important to know is the string "10".

- In decimal "10" = 10 (decimal)
- In binary "10" = 2 (decimal)
- In hexadecimal "10" = 16 (decimal)
- In octal "10" = 8 (decimal)

Comment: Your answer is helpful +1, checkout the comments thread and consider revising your answer with some examples if you can. That would help me greatly. Thank you.